# Postmates Tracking URL Error - LatLng or LatLngLiteral with finite coordinates: in property lat: NaN is not an accepted value

Tags: postmates

I am using the Postmates developer API to create a delivery in the sandbox. The delivery is created successfully and an external tracking URL is included in the response.

However, If I navigate to the tracking URL in a browser, the google map displayed has errors. Because of this it is not possible to track the location of the delivery driver.

The error I can see in the chrome console for the is:
`LatLng or LatLngLiteral with finite coordinates: in property lat: NaN is not an accepted value`

How can I resolve this error? I believe that this may be a problem on Postmates side.

[image: Tracking URL Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Postmates tracking URL is broken in the sandbox.

If your application is subscribed to the webhooks, the "robo" courier location lat/lng are correctly updated, however this is never reflected on the map.